# defining a struct as extern

Tags: c, structure

I am working with multiple files wherein all the files are linked. I have a structure which is to be used in most of the files.

This is what I am doing: I am initialising the structure in one file, data.c and I am defining it in another file, user.c . I have done this because the code sequence is in such a way that data is initialised in the main() function by calling a function data_init() which is in data.c, and the value of the structure is read from a socket in user.c

Because this structure is refernced in many other files, I have declared it as extern in data.h (because I have initialised the structure in data.c)

Now the problem is I am using this structure in file3.c, where I should get the value as defined in user.c, but I am receiving a value which was previously on the structure. Not the current value which is read into the structure in user.c.

I don't understand why this mistake has happened.  I cannot attach the code because the structure is referenced in too many files.

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.
Thanks!

Edit: I am using following files. I am sorry for extreme delay.
PS: other than the structure I have also defined a flag as extern, whose value I access in file3.c is not as expected.

types.h:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
 int num;
 char name[10];
}struct1;

typedef struct
{
  int num;
  char status[10];
}struct2;
```

data.c

```
#include"data.h"

//Globals:
struct1 packet;
struct2 packet2;

void data_init(void)
{
  memset(packet, 0 ,sizeof(packet));
  memset(packet2, 0, sizeof(packet2));
}
```

data.h:

```
#include"types.h"

extern struct1 packet;
extern struct2 packet2;

void data_int(void);
```

user.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#include"data.h"
#include "user.h"
#include "file3.h"

//Globals:
 int flag = 0;

void read_socket(void)
{
  int bytes, number;

  bytes = recv(cli_sock, &packet, sizeof(packet), MSG_DONTWAIT);
  if (bytes > 0)
  {
     flag = 1;
     number = packet.num
     switch(number)
     {
         //cases depending on value of number
         case 3:
         case 4:
          check_param(); //function in file3.c
          break;
     }
   }
}
```

user.h:

```
extern int flag;
```

file2.c

```
#include"data.h"

void write_socket(void)
{
  serialise_send(&packet2); //send data after serialisation
  flag = 0;
}
```

file3.c

```
#include"data.h"
#include"file2.h"


void check_param(void)
{
   if(flag) // sometimes the value of the flag is also not set
   {
      int number;

      number = packet1.num;
      if (number > 2) // this is where I dont get the cuurent value of   the structure which is read in user.c
      {
         printf("\n%d\n",number);
         packet2.age = number;
         packet2.name = "success";
         write_to_socket(); // function in file2.c
      }

   }
}
```

main.c

```
#include"data.h"

 void main()
 {
  data_init();
  poll_add(); //add poll functions for sockets to poll infinitely
  while((polling)); //if poll returns success for infinite time, program stays here
 }
```

Comment: Structures themselves aren't extern. Instances of that struct could be.

Comment: Since reading into the structure initializes it too, it isn't 100% clear that the `data_init()` code is necessary, but so far, it sounds about right.  The `file3.c` code shouldn't have any problems if it includes `data.h`.  If you do have a problem still, you need to review how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and provide us with one.  It'll need 3 files for this: `data.h`, `user.c` and `file3.c` (and you can add a `main()` to one of the two source files for the MCVE).  The code will be 10 lines or so per file.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger(`gdb`, whose `watch` command should be useful) &  [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: I am developing this application on a remote embedded processor, I am using printf after wherever neccessary to check the values of the variables I am using. Is using gdb a better or the only option left?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the structure variable in `.h` file

For Eg;

```
struct abc
{
  //members
};

extern struct abc val;
```

Now include the `.h` file in all the files.
Then all files will have same view of the structure.
Make sure you define the structure variable in one of the files.

Comment: This echoes more or less what is described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the problem is I am using this structure in file3.c, where I
>   should get the value as defined in user.c, but I am receiving a value
>   which was previously on the structure. Not the current value which is
>   read into the structure in user.c.

You read into the structure object `packet` in user.c, but in file3.c you examine the different structure object `packet1`.